# Visual Studio Report Designer Table

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, report, rdlc

I am using visual studio 2015 to create a report in C#.
I want to create a table which has three columns 
First column should have dates (or a range of dates) that i can provide. 
The second column should have count of values in a column(say Admission Date) against that date in the database table
the third column should have count of values in another column(say Discharge Date)
against the dates in the first column, also from the same database table

Can anyone guide if and how this possible in Report Designer